# Flutter: Fixing 'BoxConstraints forces an infinite width' Error in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter app where I have a ListView.builder widget inside a HomePage, and I'm getting the error message: "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width." This error seems to be related to the layout of my widgets, but I'm having trouble pinpointing the exact cause.

```
import "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter/rendering.dart";
import "package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart";
import "package:provider/provider.dart";
import "package:user_interface/const.dart";

import "../../test.dart";

class UserImageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ImageProvider? _userImage;

  ImageProvider? get userImage => _userImage;

  void setUserImage(ImageProvider? userImage) {
    _userImage = userImage;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<String> _items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4'];

  String? _selectedValue;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? _user;
  final UserImageProvider _userImageProvider = UserImageProvider();

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    _user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (_user != null && _user!.photoURL != null) {
      _userImageProvider.setUserImage(NetworkImage(_user!.photoURL!));
    }
  }

  final List<Widget> tiles = [
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 150,
      height: 76,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Tile 1'),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      width: 150,
      height: 76,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Tile 2'),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: 150,
      height: 76,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Tile 3'),
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            maxRadius: 35,
                            child: Provider<UserImageProvider>(
                              create: (context) => _userImageProvider,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 35,
                                backgroundImage: _userImageProvider.userImage,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("Location",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    )),
                                DropdownButton<String>(
                                  style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                  value: _selectedValue,
                                  dropdownColor: Colors.white70,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.pin_drop),
                                  iconSize: 25,
                                  items: [
                                    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: "Location 1",
                                      child: Text("Location 1"),
                                    ),
                                    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: "Location 2",
                                      child: Text("Location 2"),
                                    ),
                                    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: "Location 3",
                                      child: Text("Location 3"),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedValue = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 37,
                          height: 32,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.notifications_active,
                            size: 35,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20),
                  child: SearchBar(
                      hintText: "Search",
                      hintStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) => GoogleFonts.inter(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                          (states) => Color(0xffd9d9d9))),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Special Offers",
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                        fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 300,
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        child: ComplicatedImageDemo())),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Top Rated Near You",
                      style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.black)),
                ),
                Container(
                    height:
                        200, // Set the height to a value that fits your layout
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                              title: Text("Text "),
                            )))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Debug Console output

```
D/EGL_emulation( 7084): app_time_stats: avg=4589.84ms min=4589.84ms max=4589.84ms count=1

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderParagraph's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
_RenderListTile._layoutBox

The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=200.0)
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError
#1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>
#2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid
#3      RenderObject.layout
#4      RenderBox.layout
#5      _RenderListTile._layoutBox
#6      _RenderListTile.performLayout
#7      RenderObject.layout
#8      RenderBox.layout
#9      RenderPadding.performLayout
#10     RenderObject.layout
#11     RenderBox.layout
#12     RenderPadding.performLayout
#13     RenderObject.layout
#14     RenderBox.layout
#15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#16     RenderObject.layout
#17     RenderBox.layout
#18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#19     RenderObject.layout
#20     RenderBox.layout
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#22     RenderObject.layout
#23     RenderBox.layout
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#25     RenderObject.layout
#26     RenderBox.layout
#27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#28     RenderObject.layout
#29     RenderBox.layout
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#31     RenderObject.layout
#32     RenderBox.layout
#33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#34     RenderObject.layout
#35     RenderBox.layout
#36     RenderSliverList.performLayout
#37     RenderObject.layout
#38     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
#39     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout
#40     RenderObject.layout
#41     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence
#42     RenderViewport._attemptLayout
#43     RenderViewport.performLayout
#44     RenderObject.layout
#45     RenderBox.layout
#46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#47     RenderObject.layout
#48     RenderBox.layout
#49     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#50     RenderObject.layout
#51     RenderBox.layout
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#53     RenderObject.layout
#54     RenderBox.layout
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#56     RenderObject.layout
#57     RenderBox.layout
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#59     RenderObject.layout
#60     RenderBox.layout
#61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#62     RenderObject.layout
#63     RenderBox.layout
#64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#65     RenderObject.layout
#66     RenderBox.layout
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#68     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#69     RenderObject.layout
#70     RenderBox.layout
#71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#72     RenderObject.layout
#73     RenderBox.layout
#74     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
#75     RenderObject.layout
#76     RenderBox.layout
#77     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
#78     RenderFlex._computeSizes
#79     RenderFlex.performLayout
#80     RenderObject.layout
#81     RenderBox.layout
#82     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout
#83     RenderObject.layout
#84     RenderBox.layout
#85     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#86     RenderObject.layout
#87     RenderBox.layout
#88     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#89     RenderObject.layout
#90     RenderBox.layout
#91     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#92     RenderObject.layout
#93     RenderBox.layout
#94     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#95     RenderObject.layout
#96     RenderBox.layout
#97     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#98     RenderObject.layout
#99     RenderBox.layout
#100    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#101    RenderObject.layout
#102    RenderBox.layout
#103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#104    RenderObject.layout
#105    RenderBox.layout
#106    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#107    RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#108    RenderObject.layout
#109    RenderBox.layout
#110    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#111    RenderObject.layout
#112    RenderBox.layout
#113    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
#114    RenderFlex._computeSizes
#115    RenderFlex.performLayout
#116    RenderObject.layout
#117    RenderBox.layout
#118    RenderPadding.performLayout
#119    RenderObject.layout
#120    RenderBox.layout
#121    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
#122    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
#123    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
#124    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#125    RenderObject.layout
#126    RenderBox.layout
#127    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#128    RenderObject.layout
#129    RenderBox.layout
#130    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#131    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#132    RenderObject.layout
#133    RenderBox.layout
#134    _RenderLayoutBuilder.performLayout
#135    RenderObject.layout
#136    RenderBox.layout
#137    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
#138    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
#139    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
#140    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#141    RenderObject.layout
#142    RenderBox.layout
#143    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#144    RenderObject.layout
#145    RenderBox.layout
#146    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#147    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#148    RenderObject.layout
#149    RenderBox.layout
#150    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
#151    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
#152    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
#153    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#154    RenderObject.layout
#155    RenderBox.layout
#156    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#157    RenderObject.layout
#158    RenderBox.layout
#159    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#160    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#161    RenderObject.layout
#162    RenderBox.layout
#163    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#164    RenderObject.layout
#165    RenderBox.layout
#166    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#167    RenderObject.layout
#168    RenderBox.layout
#169    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#170    RenderObject.layout
#171    RenderBox.layout
#172    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#173    RenderObject.layout
#174    RenderBox.layout
#175    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#176    RenderObject.layout
#177    RenderBox.layout
#178    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#179    RenderObject.layout
#180    RenderBox.layout
#181    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#182    RenderObject.layout
#183    RenderBox.layout
#184    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#185    RenderObject.layout
#186    RenderBox.layout
#187    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#188    RenderObject.layout
#189    RenderBox.layout
#190    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#191    RenderOffstage.performLayout
#192    RenderObject.layout
#193    RenderBox.layout
#194    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#195    RenderObject.layout
#196    RenderBox.layout
#197    _RenderTheaterMixin.performLayout
#198    RenderObject.layout
#199    RenderBox.layout
#200    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#201    RenderObject.layout
#202    RenderBox.layout
#203    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#204    RenderObject.layout
#205    RenderBox.layout
#206    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#207    RenderObject.layout
#208    RenderBox.layout
#209    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#210    RenderObject.layout
#211    RenderBox.layout
#212    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#213    RenderObject.layout
#214    RenderBox.layout
#215    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#216    RenderObject.layout
#217    RenderBox.layout
#218    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#219    RenderObject.layout
#220    RenderBox.layout
#221    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#222    RenderObject.layout
#223    RenderBox.layout
#224    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#225    RenderObject.layout
#226    RenderBox.layout
#227    RenderView.performLayout
#228    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
#229    PipelineOwner.flushLayout
#230    RendererBinding.drawFrame
#231    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#232    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#233    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#234    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#235    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure>
#239    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderListTile#6e84b relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: _RenderListTile#6e84b relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=200.0)
    size: MISSING
    title: RenderParagraph#48e6e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        textAlign: start
        textDirection: ltr
        softWrap: wrapping at box width
        overflow: clip
        locale: en_US
        maxLines: unlimited
        text: TextSpan
            debugLabel: ((englishLike titleMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView titleMedium)).copyWith
            inherit: false
            color: Color(0xdd000000)
            family: Roboto
            size: 16.0
            weight: 400
            baseline: alphabetic
            decoration: TextDecoration.none
            "Text "
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#6e84b relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#90f25 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#614b7 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#c865a relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#b8242 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#0c18c relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderMouseRegion#d27f0 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#4dc2a relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b59d7 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 546 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#614b7 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Restarted application in 1,436ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal ListView provides infinite width and the ListTile is trying to take infinite width, this is causing the render issue. You can provide a fixed with on `ListTile`

```dart
ListView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
itemBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
  width: 200, //based on your need
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text("Text "),
  ),
),
```

You may also like `PageView`.